# Is index out of range an error error in python for arp monitoring?

Tags: python, network-programming

I am writing a Network IDS with a sample code received. However, when I am trying to run the code on a portion to get the details of arp table, i am receiving an error Index out of Range in python 3.

```
def get_default_gateway(self)->str:
    with os.popen('arp -a') as f:
        data = f.read()
    line = re.findall('([-.0-9]+)\s+([-0-9a-f]{17})\s+(\w+)',data)
    ip_gateway = line[0][0]
    mac_gateway = line[0][1]

    return ip_gateway, mac_gateway


def check_mac_change(self, ip, mac)->int:
    ret = 0
    ip_gw, mac_gw = self.get_default_gateway()
    if mac_gw != mac:
        ret = 1

    return ret
```

Error Message:

```
 >> Python IDS starting ...
 Initializing TCP Open Ports ....Done Traceback (most recent call
 last):   File "/home/kali/Downloads/pythonP3/AS.py", line 119, in
 <module>
     main()   File "/home/kali/Downloads/pythonP3/AS.py", line 100, in main
     ip_gw, mac_gw = ids.get_default_gateway()

                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "/home/kali/Downloads/pythonP3/AS.py", line 70, in get_default_gateway
     ip_gateway = line[0][0]
                   ~~^^^ IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can someone please help me?

I did try to change the array, but still resulted in error since it requires the array. Tried some alternatives but still same error.

Comment: Can you show full error message?

Comment: Fix the indentation of the shown code.

Comment: Please copy-paste the error instead of adding screenshot.

Comment: Looks like regex pattern used in `re.findall` does not match anything and it returns empty list.